# LuxonJs formating date

Tags: javascript, luxon

I am getting from the DB a date in UTC

example: `2021-06-14T16:00:30.000Z`

The idea is to change this date to LOCAL date so the output needs to be

```
2021-06-14T12:00:30.000Z
```

The problem is that doesn't matter what methods of Luxon use, I don't get that specific format (YYYY-mm-ddTHH:mm:ssZ)

How can I do this?

this piece of code is where I will put the Date getting from the DB, just need that format

```
const d = DateTime.fromISO('2021-06-14T16:00:30.000Z', { zone: 'America/Santiago' });
```

Comment: `d` is a `DateTime` object. It has a [`toFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toFormat) method on it. I think you might be disappointed, because the "Z" in that format means Zulu, which means UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISO format is basically [date]T[localtime][offset]. The offset tells you with what UTC offset the local time is expressed. It could be like `-04:00` (four hours behind UTC) or it could be "Z", which means +00:00, and generally implies not just the offset, but that the zone is UTC.

So the problem is that with a "Z" on it, your expected string specifically indicates that it's *not* a local time, even though you've explicitly converted your DB's UTC time to a Santiago local time. In other words, the string you want specifies a *different time* than the DateTime object represents. That's why Luxon doesn't have a convenient method to do what you want; it doesn't really make sense.

So here are a few options:

```js
d.toISO() //=> "2021-06-14T12:00:30.000-04:00", probably what you want
d.toISO({ includeOffset: false }) //=> "2021-06-14T12:00:30.000", if you don't want the offset
d.toUTC().toISO() // "2021-06-14T16:00:30.000Z", back to UTC
```

If you really want the local time but with a Z, you can accomplish this, but note that anything parsing it will interpret it as expressing a different time (not a different local time, but a different millisecond in the history of the world) than the time in your DB, off by four hours:

```js
d.toISO({ includeOffset: false }) + "Z"; // => "2021-06-14T12:00:30.000Z"

// OR

d.setZone("utc", { keepLocalTime: true }).toISO() // => "2021-06-14T12:00:30.000Z"
```